# Where do you collect hire cars at Noumea Tontouta airport?

Tags: airports, car-rentals, new-caledonia, nou

The [Noumea Tontouta airport website](http://www.tontouta-aeroport.nc/index.php) has a [map of the main floor on their site](http://www.tontouta-aeroport.nc/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=41&Itemid=78), which just has an arrow pointing into the distance for hire cars. On the [overall airport plan](http://www.tontouta-aeroport.nc/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=39&Itemid=75) there doesn't seem to be any hire car areas marked.

[image: Map of the airport from www.tontouta-aeroport.nc]

Where are the hire cars in relation to the airport terminal? Short walk? Long walk? Shuttle bus ride?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From one of the [rental companies](http://au.sixt.com/car-rental/new-caledonia/tontouta/noumea-la-tontouta-intairport):

> The car hire service facility is located just metres away from the
>   main terminal entrance of Noumea la tontouta intairport.

With Google Maps, you can see there are only a couple of car park areas at the airport, and both are within 500m of anywhere at the airport.

So the answer, I believe, would be "a short walk at most".

Comment: +1, rented a car here recently and the rental car shops (booths, really) are immediately outside the terminal on the right side, signposted *Location des voitures*.